# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '06/30/2012' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

I'm having issues trying to set two variables, a From Date, and a To Date. Once I solve the issue for one, the other will be easy enough to figure out. I'm getting the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '06/30/2012' to data type int.

It's worth noting that I'm using a view to bring various tables together, and then executing the ones I want via `sp_executesql`. When I print my query I can see that it's recognizing the `@fromdate` as 0, perhaps that's the issue..

```
 declare @fromdate nvarchar
 declare @todate nvarchar
 select @fromdate = '03/01/1999'
 select @todate = ''

 IF @fromdate <> ''
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' and convert (nvarchar,document_Date,101) > '+@fromdate+''
END

 if @todate <> ''
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' and convert(nvarchar,document_date,101) >  '+@todate+''
END
```

The column `document_date` is datetime. Any ideas? If so, could you explain why this is occurring so I can learn and avoid it happening in the future? I've included the print SQL below.

```
 SELECT  [system_status]      
  ,[document_status_code]      
  ,[rpt_category]      
  ,[category]      
  ,[user_status_cd]      
  ,[user_status]      
  ,[assigned_to_id]      
  ,[assigned]      
  ,[assigned_to_date]      
  ,[owner_id]      
  ,[owner]      
  ,[rpt_acct_code]      
  ,[acct_name]      
  ,[rpt_title]      
  ,[job_name]      
  ,[logged_time]      
  ,[rpt_format_type]      
  ,[rpt_run_id]      
  ,[rpt_doc_id]      
  ,[rpt_id]      
  ,[rpt_filename]      
  ,[rpt_file_path]      
  ,[rpt_run_name]      
  ,[sla_start_date]      
  ,[sla_due_date]      
  ,[sla_completed_date]      
  ,[sla_status]      
  ,[SLA_Days]
  ,[Document_Date] 
  FROM VW_Document_Main
  WHERE 1=1 and convert (nvarchar,document_Date,101) > 0 
  order by document_status_code  ,owner_id
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 : Version - 10.50.2500.0

Comment: Thank you. Please always tag your questions with the version, this prevents us from having to guess and ensures we use a solution that is most appropriate for your version. It isn't always relevant, but it's relevant often enough that I probably have to ask more often than I don't.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that you do not have a length on your declaration of `@fromdate`

It is only returning the first character because you do not have a length. The declaration should say:

```
declare @fromdate nvarchar(10)
declare @todate nvarchar(10)
```

Since you do not have a length, it is returning `0` which is the first character.

Secondly, you are also comparing string values of the dates, you should be comparing the date values.

```
declare @fromdate datetime
declare @todate datetime
```

Then your code could be:

```
SELECT @sql = @sql + ' and document_Date > '''+convert(varchar(10), @fromdate, 101)+''''
```

Comment: While true, that does not solve the root problem that he's doing inequality comparisons based on dates in the format MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: @EricJ. I agree that is why i said _part of the problem_. :)

Answer (score 0):

The literal

```
'03/01/1999'
```

is a string literal.  You are converting `document_Date` to a varchar, then doing an inequality comparison

```
and convert (nvarchar,document_Date,101) > '+@fromdate
```

Since the dates are not formatted YYYYMMDD, the comparison is unlikely to produce the comparison you expect.

If `@fromdate` for example is '04/01/1900', it will be *greater than* '03/01/1999' because '04' is greater than '03'.

Instead, convert @fromdate to the same type as document_Date, e.g.

```
AND document_Date > convert(datetime, @fromdate)
```

Comment: Is it possible to rearrange data types so that I'm not getting this inequality comparison?

Comment: However, when I set @fromdate as datetime, it'll populate the error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0):

If the column document_date is already a datetime, why not declare  declare @fromdate 
and @todate as datetime as well, then your code will be simpler and you won't have to do any conversion. It seems to me the conversion is unnecessary for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also it doesn't seem like you need to use dynamic SQL for this

Comment: Well, dynamic SQL might not be the most terrible thing in the world here. When you start adding `WHERE col >= @param OR @param IS NULL` it can be very tough for SQL Server to come up with an optimal plan that works for all combinations of parameters. With dynamic SQL you get a good chance of having a good plan for each variation.

Comment: It might be justified, I just think from what is shown here it looks possible to accomplish what he needs without dynamic SQL and especially without casting back and forth between Datetime and Varchar

Answer (score 0):

## Problem #1

```
declare @fromdate nvarchar
select @fromdate = '03/01/1999'
```

Why are you defining these as *Unicode* strings, never mind [strings without a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)? Why are you using an ambiguous, unreliable format for the literal? Is that March 1st or January 3rd? Are you sure your instance of SQL Server agrees with you?

## Problem #2

```
SELECT @sql = @sql + ' and convert (nvarchar,document_Date,101) > '+@fromdate+''
```

Why are you converting your column to a *Unicode* string, never mind a [string without a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)? Why are you comparing it as a string? You know that `'05/05/2010'` is greater than `'02/21/2015`', when compared as a string, right?

## Solution

Stop using ambiguous formats. Stop thinking that dates are strings and should be compared as such.

How about:

```
DECLARE @fromdate DATETIME = '19990301'; -- guessing you meant March 1st. 
      -- See why ambiguous formats are bad and you should never use them?

...
SELECT @sql += ' AND document_Date > @fromdate;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@fromdate DATETIME', @fromdate;
```

Now you don't have to do any conversions at all.

Comment: I now understand why the ambiguity in selecting dates can be problematic. However, if end users will be inputting a date 03/01/1999 is more feasible than entering 19990301.. Is it possible to convert the output of the datetime?

Comment: @user2191477 stop letting your users type in whatever they feel like - your users can also type in 03/01/1999 and how will you know they didn't mean Jan 3? You can easily control input format by using a calendar control or dropdowns and assembling a proper, unambiguous format like `19990301` before sending it to SQL Server, or by passing in a proper DateTime parameter from your application in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. It's definitely a learning process, and I am trying. Thanks for the input